# Circle border is showing behind the section. How to fix?

Tags: html, css

The circle border on the right side is showing behind the last page on the right.

The circle border on the left side is showing well. How can I fix the right one?

I tried to use `z-index` for the section and the circle but it doesn't work.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

/*Main settings*/
.slide {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 300vw;
    transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100vh);
    transform-origin: top left;
}

.one {
    background: #151515;
}

.two {
    background: #000000;
}

.three {
    background: #151515;
}

.four {
    background: #00dfdf;
}

.outer-wrapper {
    width: 100vh;
    height: 100vw;
    transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-100vh);
    transform-origin: top left;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    scrollbar-width: none;
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

.circle1 {
    float: left;
    margin: 13em -11em;
    width: 20em;
    height: 20em;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: solid 0.8em black;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.5em white;
    outline-offset: 5em;
    outline: solid 0.1em rgb(181, 181, 181);
    background-image: url("images/2.png");
    background-size: cover;
}

.circle2 {
    z-index: 99;
    float: right;
    margin: 13em -5em;
    width: 20em;
    height: 20em;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: solid 0.8em black;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.5em white;
    outline-offset: 5em;
    outline: solid 0.1em rgb(181, 181, 181);
    background-image: url("images/2.png");
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="outer-wrapper">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="slide one"></div>
            <div class="slide two">
                <div class="circle1"></div>
                <div class="circle2"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="slide three"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I tried to use `z-index` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple fix would be to add `position: relative` to the second circle:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

/*Main settings*/
.slide {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 300vw;
    transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100vh);
    transform-origin: top left;
}

.one {
    background: #151515;
}

.two {
    background: #000000;
}

.three {
    background: #151515;
}

.four {
    background: #00dfdf;
}

.outer-wrapper {
    width: 100vh;
    height: 100vw;
    transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-100vh);
    transform-origin: top left;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    scrollbar-width: none;
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

.circle1 {
    float: left;
    margin: 13em -11em;
    width: 20em;
    height: 20em;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: solid 0.8em black;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.5em white;
    outline-offset: 5em;
    outline: solid 0.1em rgb(181, 181, 181);
    background-image: url("images/2.png");
    background-size: cover;
}

.circle2 {
    z-index: 99;
    float: right;
    margin: 13em -5em;
    width: 20em;
    height: 20em;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: solid 0.8em black;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.5em white;
    outline-offset: 5em;
    outline: solid 0.1em rgb(181, 181, 181);
    background-image: url("images/2.png");
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="outer-wrapper">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="slide one"></div>
            <div class="slide two">
                <div class="circle1"></div>
                <div class="circle2"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="slide three"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```